# sed regex not working in shell script

Tags: shell-script, sed, regular-expression

Given:

```
~$ cat .test-profile
export ADMIN_EMAIL=info@mail.com
export MONGODB_URI='mongodb+srv://administrator:abcdef@mysite-cluster-n1qub.mongodb.net/test?retryWrites=true&w=majority'
```

I wrote the following shell script to replace the variable values:

```
BASH_PROFILE="$HOME/.test-profile"
MONGODB_URI="mongodb+srv://administrator:abcdef@mysite-cluster-n1qub.mongodb.net/mysite_development?retryWrites=true&w=majority"

INSERT_ENV_VAR () {
  if [[ -z "$2" ]]
    then
      echo "Failed to retrieve $1"
   else
    if grep -q "$1" "$BASH_PROFILE"; then
      # Cannot use / delimiter, for value can contain /
      sed -in -E "s|(export $1=)[a-zA-Z0-9@.:\/=&\-\?\+]+|\1$2|g" "$BASH_PROFILE"
    else
      echo "export $1=$2" >> "$BASH_PROFILE"
    fi
  fi
}

INSERT_ENV_VAR 'ADMIN_EMAIL' 'bob@gmail.com'
INSERT_ENV_VAR 'MONGODB_URI' $MONGODB_URI
```

While the ADMIN_EMAIL variable is replaced fine, the MONGODB_URI variable is not being replaced. And I believe it has to do something with the character class [] inside of the regex. But I am not sure what. I tried it in a programming language like ruby and it found the match. But with sed it isn't finding the match. Why?

This is what I expect `.test-profile` to look like afterwards:

```
export ADMIN_EMAIL=bob@gmail.com
export MONGODB_URI='mongodb+srv://administrator:abcdef@mysite-cluster-n1qub.mongodb.net/mysite_development?retryWrites=true&w=majority'
```

Notice 'mysite_development' replaces 'test'.

Comment: The problem seems to be related with the `'` character. Try your sed with `(export MONGODB_URI=)[a-zA-Z0-9@.:\/=&\-\?\+']+` (adds a `'` to the list of valid characters).

Comment: @PauloTomé adding ' seems to produce a result but not completely replacing old value with new value.

Comment: You have unescaped `&` in the replacement string.

Comment: Also why use such a complicated regex? Why not `"s|(export $1=).*|\1$2|"`? And why use `g`? But you still have to escape `&` in `$2`.

Comment: I have - did you escape your ampersands?

Comment: I forgot to mention that I also got rid of the `-n` in the sed options: why are you using that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Escaping the ampersand in the definition of MONGODB_URI in the script and simplifying the regex, getting rid of the `-n` and getting rid of the unnecessary `g` in the sed, we end up with this (the test profile is named differently in this version, but it should be clear what to do):

```
BASH_PROFILE="/tmp/test_profile"
MONGODB_URI="mongodb+srv://administrator:abcdef@mysite-cluster-n1qub.mongodb.net/mysite_development?retryWrites=true\&w=majority"

INSERT_ENV_VAR () {
  if [[ -z "$2" ]]
    then
      echo "Failed to retrieve $1"
   else
    if grep -q "$1" "$BASH_PROFILE"; then
      # Cannot use / delimiter, for value can contain /
      sed -i -E "s;(export $1=).*;\1$2;" "$BASH_PROFILE"
    else
      echo "export $1=$2" >> "$BASH_PROFILE"
    fi
  fi
}

INSERT_ENV_VAR 'ADMIN_EMAIL' 'bob@gmail.com'
INSERT_ENV_VAR 'MONGODB_URI' $MONGODB_URI
```

and running this with the test profile, I get:

```
export ADMIN_EMAIL=bob@gmail.com
export MONGODB_URI=mongodb+srv://administrator:abcdef@mysite-cluster-n1qub.mongodb.net/mysite_development?retryWrites=true&w=majority
```

Comment: Yes, I deleted the comment earlier because it did work.

Comment: This will result in some inconsistency – when `grep` succeeds and `sed` is used the replacement made by sed won't contain a `backslash` before the `&`, but if the append-`echo` is used the `\\` remains

Answer (score 0):

```bsh
sed -i "/export $1=/{i export $1='$2'
    ;d}" "$BASH_PROFILE"
```

This will allow you to use `sed` without needing to replace `&` with `\&`

- `grep -q` could have the options `-F` and also `-m 1`